# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core-ktx:

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle, google-play-services

[Image link containing screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oauvE.png)
I am using Kotlin for my android app. I am unable to finish my Gradle Build due to this error :
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core-ktx:

I tried all possible solutions available on stackoverflow. I have already downloaded the latest google play services from the SDK manager. I placed maven{url...} in my all repositories, yet can't fix this error. Even tried adding version specification in my implementations. Please help me with this!!

This below is my build.gradle file :-

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

These are the dependencies added to the code :-

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:19.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

Comment: Thanks man! It worked. Glad you spared your time to help.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try this, if you are using the bom library.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
```